# Wrapping GMP in Java

Tags: java, windows, cygwin, wrapper, gmp

I am trying to use GMP in a Java program which I am writing.

I am attempting to use the wrapper found here:
https://bitbucket.org/dfdeshom/gmp-java/overview

It says that one must simply type in "make"...

I am pretty lost.

I have GMP installed on my computer (I think), and I have Cygwin installed on my computer. (Which I used to install GMP).

When I load the directory of the unzipped downloaded file from the link above in Cygwin and type in "make", I receive this output:

```
javac -Xlint org/dfdeshom/math/GMP.java
make: javac: Command not found
Makefile:12: recipe for target `jni' failed
make: *** [jni] Error 127
```

I have very little experience/knowledge regarding the Java Native Interface and I am unsure of how to go about "making" this file. According to the link above, a successful "make" will result in the creation of a GMP.jar file.

How do I do this properly? Very detailed explanations are appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The important bit is this line

> make: javac: Command not found

this suggests you don't have the java compiler on your path.
This could be caused by a couple of reasons:

1. your path is incorrect.
2. you only have the JRE installed and not the JDK.